# why is the ending of this demonstrative adj in -e not -er?

Tags: adjective-ending, wechselpraeposition

> Kommt, wir setzen uns auf diese Bank.

where `die Bank, die Bänke` is a bench in the park.

Shouldn't it be: *auf dies**er** Bank* ? Isn't it a strong adj. ending as to this [Wikibook article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Adjectives_and_Adverbs)?

Comment: The question would be clearer if you indicated which case you think this is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In German, we have the two verbs *sitzen* and *setzen* that both translate to the English *to sit*. *Sitzen* is used when you are already sitting at the location, which is why it demands the dative case:

> Wo sitzt ihr? – Wir sitzen auf [dieser](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#dies_(Deutsch)) Bank.
>
> <sub>(Where do you sit? – We are sitting on this bench.)</sub>

*Setzen*, in contrast, is used to express that you are going to sit down, that is, you fulfill a movement towards the place. Therefore, *setzen* demands the accusative case:

> Wohin setzt ihr euch? – Wir setzen uns auf [diese](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#dies_(Deutsch)) Bank.
>
> <sub>Where do you sit (down)? – We are sitting (down) on(to) this bench.</sub>

Notice that [*dies*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#dies_(Deutsch)) is not an adjective but a demonstrative pronoun, which is why the rules of strong/weak/mixed adjective declension do not apply here.

Comment: I did suspect _setzen_ as the cause of there being an Akk. instead of Dat. ending (_diese_ not _dieser_) but was totally unaware of the difference with _sitzen_, so thank you so much for pointing this out. However I still think that "diese" is a demonstrative _adjective_, not a pronoun, since it is immediately followed by the noun it refers to, "Bank". That would validate the Oklahoma mnemonic of the [German Grammar Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Adjectives_and_Adverbs) (Akk. ends with **-e** for strong declension, since there are no _der_ or _ein_ articles).

Comment: The page you linked states correctly *The strong adjective endings are nearly the same as the der-word endings, with the exception of masculine and neuter adjectives in the genitive case (both marked in bold).* That shows *dies* is a der-word, not an adjective, because its masculine and neuter genitive endings are -es. Not -en.

Comment: @WobblyWindows, in German they are called *Demonstrativpronomen*, English terminology may differ. In that case, expect same confusion here ;) For sitzen/setzen think lie/lay without the confusion.

Comment: @WobblyWindows It is not really the verb, it is the preposition "auf" that takes different cases depending on whether you are talking about state/location or about transition/direction. Lots of prepositions work like that.

Comment: Also what wonderbear said. "Auf" is not in the *aus, bei, mit, nach, seit, von, zu* -list :-)

Comment: You have cause and effect mixed up. It is not an adjective because it does not inflect like one *and the grammarians didn't know what to do with it*. The made up jargon is fairly irrelevant at this point. The answer is good without it.